There was a problem parsing the package - Unreal Engine 5 - Android
When I install the APK that I generate with UE5.3.2 in a blank project and in my game the error "There was a problem parsing the package" appears, it does not allow me to install it.
I religiously followed the steps in the documentation: https://dev.epicgames.com/documentation/en-us/unreal-engine/how-to-set-up-android-sdk-and-ndk-for-your-unreal-engine-development-environment

I installed Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 May 24, 2023
I installed the SDK from Android Studio.
I installed the Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest).
I restarted my computer and ran UE5/Engine/Extras/Android/SetupAndroid.bat (for the paths).
In the game I configured Edit > Project Settings > Platforms > Android > Android SDK

My game is packaged correctly, it generates the APK, I just haven't been able to install it on my cell phone yet (I am allowed to use applications from unknown developers, I am in developer mode, and the Android version is within those allowed, 11). In addition to trying it with my cell phone, I also tried it with the Android emulator for Windows BlueStacks.
I've watched tutorials to make sure I'm doing the right thing and haven't found the problem. I tried ETC2 and ASTC.



